# Dialog Button Box

Tags: qt

Как добавить слот к кнопке, например, "ОК", при использовании Dialog Button Box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Можно воспользоваться методом [`QDialogButtonBox::buttons()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qdialogbuttonbox.html#buttons), который выдаст список всех кнопок диалога, найти среди них нужную и привязать слот к её сигналу.
2. Можно воспользоваться методом [`QDialogButtonBox::button(StandardButton)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qdialogbuttonbox.html#button), которому в качестве аргумента передаётся "тип" кнопки. Результатом вызова будет указатель на кнопку.
3. Можно добавить кнопку в баттон-бокс самостоятельно с помощью одного из перегруженных методов `addButton`:

   - [`void addButton(QAbstractButton*, ButtonRole)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qdialogbuttonbox.html#addButton),
   - [`QPushButton* addButton(const QString&, ButtonRole)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qdialogbuttonbox.html#addButton-1),
   - [`QPushButton* addButton(StandardButton)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qdialogbuttonbox.html#addButton-2)
4. Но самым правильным методом будет не использовать то, чего разработчики не предполагали. Если Вам нужно "выцарапать" кнопку из диалога, значит, у Вас проблема с архитектурой либо с проектированием. Если нужно особое поведение *конкретной* кнопки, нужно создавать *отдельную* кнопку. Или же использовать предусмотренный интерфейс баттон-бокса - его слоты:

   - [`accepted()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qdialogbuttonbox.html#accepted) (вызывается при нажатии кнопки с ролью `AcceptRole` или `YesRole`);
   - [`clicked(QAbstractButton*)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qdialogbuttonbox.html#clicked) (вызывается при нажатии любой кнопки диалога, указатель на кнопку будет передан как параметр сигнала);
   - [`helpRequested()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qdialogbuttonbox.html#helpRequested)(вызывается при нажатии кнопки с ролью `HelpRole`);
   - [`rejected()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qdialogbuttonbox.html#rejected) (вызывается при нажатии кнопки с ролью `RejectRole` или `NoRole`).

Answer (score 0):

На примере кнопки 'ok':

```
self.button_ok = self.buttonBox.button(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
self.button_ok.clicked.connect(self.open_new_dialog)
```

На примере кнопки 'retry':

```
self.button_retry = self.buttonBox.button(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Retry)
self.button_retry.clicked.connect(lambda: self.end_dialog(0))
```